# How to average based on data range in a difference table in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

With two tables, `Values` and `dates`, I would like to get the average value between the date ranges.
`Values` looks like:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 10:00 | 1 |
| 2023-01-01 11:00 | 2 |
| 2023-01-02 10:00 | 4 |
| 2023-01-04 10:00 | 4 |
| 2023-01-07 10:00 | 4 |

and `dates` looks like

| Group | StartDay | EndDay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-05 |
| 2 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-10 |

As you can see, the date ranges can overlap.

I am trying to calculate the averages over these ranges, so in this example the output should be something along the lines of

| Group | StartDay | EndDay | Mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-05 | 2.75 |
| 2 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-10 | 4 |

Currently my code looks like (all one line):

`Values.groupby(np.where(Values['Date'].between(Dates['StartDay'],Dates['EndDay']),'pre','post'))['value'].mean()`

however this results in
`ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

This was based on [other similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65586029/get-the-average-for-specific-range-of-dates-in-pandas), however does not appear to apply here due to it being over two tables / using ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
# convert the values to datetime (if not already):
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['StartDay'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['StartDay'])
df2['EndDay'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['EndDay'])

df1 = df1.sort_values(by='Date').set_index('Date')

df2['Mean'] = df2.apply(lambda x: df1[x['StartDay']:x['EndDay']].mean(), axis=1)
print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
   Group   StartDay     EndDay  Mean
0      1 2023-01-01 2023-01-05  2.75
1      2 2023-01-03 2023-01-10  4.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some form of inequality join - if that is the case, you can use [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to get your results, before grouping - should be faster than `apply`, depending on the data size:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df1 = pd.read_clipboard(sep="\t", engine='python', parse_dates = ['Date'])
df2 = pd.read_clipboard(sep="\t", engine='python', parse_dates = ['StartDay', 'EndDay'])

(df1
.conditional_join(
    df2, 
    # column from left, column from right, comparator
    ('Date', 'StartDay', '>='),  
    ('Date', 'EndDay', '<='), 
    # depending on the data size,
    # you might get more performance with numba
    use_numba = False,
    df_columns = 'Value')
.groupby(df2.columns.tolist())
.Value
.mean()
)

Group  StartDay    EndDay    
1      2023-01-01  2023-01-05    2.75
2      2023-01-03  2023-01-10    4.00
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```